# Direct connection betwen two Ethernet-to-wifi adapters

Tags: ethernet, ieee-802.11

I currently have two computers connected via ethernet and a switch, using static ip-addresses. I would like to connect a third computer, this time wirelessly. And I am wondering whether the setup in the image below would work. Essentially, I would like the wi-fi "bridge" to behave just like a wired ethernet connection. I have found Ethernet-to-wifi adapters by IOGEAR, for instance GWU637, however it does seem like they must be connected via a wi-fi capable router. Thus, I wondered whether my original setup is even possible? And if it is, are anyone aware of a product that can deliver such a bridge?

Link to GWU637: https://www.iogear.com/product/GWU637/

[image: Illustration of the setup]

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explcitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bridge Ethernet wirelessly by using two WAPs, one of them connecting to the other in client mode. Using a directional antenna, you can bridge several hundred meters or even some km outdoor.

There are many devices on the market, recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, however. You need to consider your requirements for bandwidth, latency, reach and reliability. Note that Wi-Fi uses free bands and can become subject to interference from many sources at any time.

Comment: Thanks, this guided me in the right direction :-)